# Django - Best way to organize/serve mostly static website?

Tags: django

My friend with very little coding experience began making a business site and passed it on to me.  Currently, it is mostly static html and css files but I want to take what he has and build on it using Django because I will be adding features like user login/auth and checkout.  I was wondering what the best thing to do with all these html and css files are and how I might go about fitting it to Django framework.

All of the content on these pages will be static but I could imagine in the future once I add a login, the header might be different to show whether or not a user is logged in.  Would I need to make separate apps for each page, include them all in one app, or just put them all in the static folder?

Comment: Hello Dylan, unfortunately the scope of this question is quite large and subjective. So i dont think you'll be able to get a full solution to your problem here. I tried my best to answer it below.

Answer (score 0):

> Would I need to make separate apps for each page

Assuming you are referring to *django apps*. Then **No**, you do not need to create a separate application for each page. *django apps* are a way to organize individual pieces of your projects.

To gain the most out of django, I would suggest looking into the `Django Template Engine` to improve the html (blocks, include and extend etc) and make it more readable and future proof ( urls, media, forms)

> just put them all in the static folder?

I'm not sure you'd be able to get away with it being in the static folder, Static files in django are used for CSS and Media files such as images, videos etc. To render a template in django you need use `render()` or `TemplateView`

I hope this helps clear up some of your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Django is a Model-View-Template (MVT) framework where you create templates (HTML files) and use Jinja syntax there to display the data passed from Django views. You don't need to create apps for each page, instead, you can define functions in an app's views.py file and then reference that view from the corresponding path (URL) from the urls.py file.

You can create a main HTML template that will be extended by each sub-page. And applying your logic to your main template's header (i.e. if/else) in the main template will affect your all pages.

My recommendation is that you should first study the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/) carefully and understand at least it's basics before starting the migration of the HTML site to Django. Django has one of the best documentation available for software on the Internet and you should be grasping the basics very quickly if you have a little programming background.